# Can NSubstitute be set up to execute any passed delegate

Tags: c#, .net, nsubstitute

I have the following interface

```
public interface IActionSecureExecuter
{
    void SecureExecuteOperation(Action action);

    T SecureExecuteOperation<T>(Func<T> action);
}
```

Now I want to mock the implementation so that it does executes the delegates that it gets as arguments. It was pretty simple with the first method:

```
m_Executer.SecureExecuteOperation(Arg.Invoke());
```

But I have troubles with the generic implementation of the second one. Is it possible to do something with that Func or I will have to do a setup for each T? I am afraid this is not possible according to that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902491/mocking-generic-method-with-nsubstitute) but I am not 100% sure. This is what I did now:

```
private void SetupInvokeAction<T>()
{
    m_Executer.SecureExecuteOperation(Arg.InvokeDelegate<Func<T>>());
}
```

I call this function in each test method. But I would really like to place that in the setup.

Comment: What should the latter method do, invoke the `Func<T>` delegate and return the result?

Comment: Actually that's the ideal result (for the mock). I am not sure how to set it up in NSubstitue, so I wanted to check if it gets called at least.

Comment: Not currently possible with NSub sorry. Each generic instance needs to be configured separately.

Comment: I raised a question based on yours https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/152 Feel free to share your thoughts there.