# How to use NSubstitute to return a generic passed in value like we do in moq?

Tags: c#, moq, nsubstitute

Imagine I want to mock the Set method of this interface to return what is being passed on the generic parameter:

```
public interface IMemoryCache
{
    TItem Set<TItem>(object key, TItem value);
}
```

Using moq I can do it this way:

```
[Fact]
public void SetupUsingMoq()
{
    Mock<IMemoryCache> mock = new();

    mock
        .Setup(x => x.Set(It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>()))
        .Returns((object _, object input) => input);

    mock.Object.Set(1, "ok").Should().Be("ok");
}
```

I've tried doing the same thing using NSubstitute but, unfortunately, this doesn't work:

```
[Fact]
public void SetupUsingNSubstitute()
{
    IMemoryCache mock = Substitute.For<IMemoryCache>();

    mock
        .Set(Arg.Any<object>(), Arg.Any<Arg.AnyType>())
        .Returns(callInfo => callInfo.ArgAt<object>(1));

    mock.Set(1, "ok").Should().Be("ok");
}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean exactly in your case?

Comment: `AssertionFailedException: Expected string to be "ok" with a length of 2, but "" has a length of 0, differs near "" (index 0).`

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17908223/1025555) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to set it up for `strings`, you can make the test pass by explicitly configuring the object for that type:

```
[Fact]
public void SetupUsingNSubstitute()
{
    IMemoryCache mock = Substitute.For<IMemoryCache>();
    mock
        .Set(Arg.Any<object>(), Arg.Any<string>())
        .Returns(callInfo => callInfo.ArgAt<string>(1));

    var actual = mock.Set(1, "ok");

    Assert.Equal("ok", actual);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to set the return value for any T.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I didn't find anything official the documentation, but the tests succeed when setting up the mock via `mock.Set(default!, Arg.Any<object>())`

```
[Fact]
public void SetupUsingNSubstitute()
{
    IMemoryCache mock = Substitute.For<IMemoryCache>();

    mock
        .Set(default!, Arg.Any<object>())
        .Returns(callInfo => callInfo.ArgAt<object>(1));

    mock.Set(1, "ok").Should().Be("ok");
    mock.Set(2, "nok").Should().Be("nok");
    mock.Set("foo", 3).Should().Be(3);
}
```

Comment: I get " NSubstitute.Exceptions.AmbiguousArgumentsException : Cannot determine argument specifications to use. Please use specifications for all arguments of the same type."

Comment: I am using NSubstitute 4.4.0 on .NET 6, what versions are you on?

Comment: NSubstitute 5.1.0 on .NET 7

Comment: Can't reproduce that exception. Running here on .NET 8, NSubstitute 5.1.0 using Test Explorer in Visual Studio 2022 17.8.2.